# Name for a horizontal line function

Tags: functions, terminology

What is the, or what are the, technical terms for a function that produces a horizontal line (all inputs map to the same output), like $f(x) = 5$?

Comment: such a function is called *constant*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *constant function*. ${}{}$